# How to insert created in JS Image() to HTML by using innerHMTL (without appendChild)?

Tags: javascript, image

I have a preloaded array of images:

```
image = new Image();
image.onload = myOnLoadFunc;
image.src = 'images/myicon.png';
myImages.push(image);
```

I would like display them on page.

I am doing something like this:

```
for (i = 0, len = myImages.length; i < len; ++i) {
    html += '<li><img src="'+myImages[i].src+'"></li>';
}
// ...
myElement.innerHTML = html;
```

And it works, except for the **re-downloading images** for the second time.

I know that I can do `myElement.appendChild(...)`, but I need to know if it is possible with `innerHTML` "method".

---

My problem is that if browser parses `'<img src='+image.src+'>'` after `innerHTML` it does not understand that it already has that `image` in memory.

I would like to avoid `appendChild` because in case of array of images it messes with the DOM several times.

Comment: For the "second time" you mean everytime you refresh the page or somthing like that?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `appendChild()`? And no, you can't convert a Node to a string of HTML, insert that and *not* trigger the browser's normal events for a new image.

Comment: Please, provide the code of the **myOnLoadFunc** function.

Comment: @DavidThomas, thank you, I updated the question. And you might just answered it. I just would like to be sure that I cannot do it with `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the preloading of the images is not done yet.

Periodically check the **complete** attribute of **image**.

Run your for cycle when **complete** turns **true**.

**Update with the code:**

```
function insertMyImages() {
    for (i = 0, len = myImages.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if ( !myImages[i].complete ) {
            setTimeout(function(){insertMyImages();},100);
            return;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0, len = myImages.length; i < len; ++i) {
        html += '<li><img src="'+myImages[i].src+'"></li>';
    }
    // ...
    myElement.innerHTML = html;
}

setTimeout(function(){insertMyImages();},100);
```

Comment: But **I do check that** with `.onload = myOnLoadFunc`. My problem is that if browser parses `<img src=image.src>` after `innerHTML` it does not understand that it already has that `image` in memory.

Comment: @Jake - **myOnLoadFunc** would be called on the first load event, which *might* be for another image.

Comment: I see some confusion here.  When you create the new list element with an img tag in it, you're creating a new img element in the DOM.  It's not the same as the image you believe you loaded in the script; all that does is make sure the image is in the cache (technically not the same as "in memory.")  How the browser chooses to load the new img element is up to the caching algorithm.  Setting the src attribute is not the same as "copying" the image in the DOM.

Comment: Also, @blue -- why wrap the call to insertMyImages in another function?  setTimeout(insertMyImages,100) works exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But there is no problem with preloading images for sure. My question is about how to tell browser that `image` is in its memory before or after `.innerHTML`.